# Is there a way of powering an incandescent light bulb without AC mains?

Tags: ac, dc, control

I'm looking to power a light bulb for a greenhouse project, but I do not have the option of using the AC mains (for safety reasons). Is there a way to power it on using a lower voltage? I have a solid state relay and a bulb and fixture lying around. Should I look into amplifiers?

I'm using the bulb to provide heat to the greenhouse (the greenhouse is very small) and I'm looking to control it using an Arduino.

Comment: Use low-voltage lighting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Should I look into amplifiers?*

Nope, amplifiers are for amplifying electrical **signals**. What you want is electrical **power**.

The solid state relay is useful. Control it from the Arduino. If you don't know how, search Google and this site for some examples.

Let the solid state relay switch on/off a low voltage (12 V perhaps) halogen bulb or a car (headlight) bulb (these are mostly halogen as well). Power it from a 12 V adapter or transformer with sufficient power (at least as much as the lightbulb needs).

If you cannot use a mains adapter use a 12 V (car) battery.

Comment: Check that your solid state relay is suitable for DC - most will only switch AC - of course you could switch low voltage AC from a transformer.

Comment: Good point, some AC relays only can switch DC on but not off ! (because there's a Thyristor inside).

Answer (score 2):

Get a car light bulb, those are rated at 12V. The most powerful ones (H4 or HB2) can output about 100W, but you can easily get less power ones if your greenhouse is really small.

Comment: Note that in an H4 there are actually two 50 W windings in one bulb. So you could run it at 50W (use one)  or 100 W (use both) and probably something like 30 W (both in series) as well (have not tried if that works though).

Answer (score 0):

You can get incandescent 12V lamps- halogens (eg. MR16) are very common and are relatively efficient. Systems are available for low voltage landscape lighting.

The wiring will have to be much thicker than for 120V or 240V lighting- imagine a modest 1000W of lighting at 120V- the current draw would be 8.3A, so you could go almost 100' (200') of inexpensive AWG 16 wire with 50W loss maximum. At 12V, the current draw will be 83A, so for 50W loss you could only go 9' (18' round trip) of thick AWG wire.

You could also consider more efficient (lumens/watt) LED lighting, but that opens a can of worms with regard to what wavelengths your particular crop craves.

Comment: The question reads "I'm using the bulb to provide **heat** to the greenhouse", so I doubt LEDs will do any good.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev There's maybe a factor of two in there- LED lamps still get hot, and we should also consider climate change. ;-)  Incandescent lamps typically have a life of a couple thousand hours at best- 250 hours for an H4 maybe- so it might be better to have a heater + LED lamp, if more heat was required (and it could be turned off when not needed).

Comment: I don't think long-term efficient is a factor here (while price probably is). If the efficiency is at stake, one should first resolve safety issues without banning mains voltage.

Comment: OP needs inefficient lighting.

Comment: LED + heater is arbitrarily inefficient, and won't burn out after 250 hours.